# unexpected go channel appearance

Tags: go

in below go func(cacheCh, dbCh <- chan Book), I don't understand why <-dbCh is needed.. can someone please explain?
I run into deadline issue without and I cannot explain what this is doing to solve this problem.
It looks like it's saying dbCh should be sending back but not sure what it is and where it's going and how it helps w/ deadlock.

__ code in question __

```
    go func(cacheCh, dbCh <- chan Book) {
        select {
            case b := <-cacheCh:
                fmt.Println("from cache")
                fmt.Println(b)
                <-dbCh
            case b := <-dbCh:
                fmt.Println("from database")
                fmt.Println(b)
```

__ entire code __
package main

```
import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var cache = map[int]Book{}
var rnd = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    mt := &sync.RWMutex{}
    cacheCh := make(chan Book)
    dbCh := make(chan Book)

    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        id := rnd.Intn(10)+1
        wg.Add(2)
        go func(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, mt *sync.RWMutex, ch chan<- Book) {
            if b,ok := queryCache(id,mt); ok {
                //fmt.Println("from cache")
                //fmt.Println(b)
                ch <- b
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(id,wg,mt,cacheCh)

        go func(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, mt *sync.RWMutex,ch chan<- Book) {
            if b,ok := queryDatabase(id,mt); ok {
                //fmt.Println("from database")
                //fmt.Println(b)
                ch <- b
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(id,wg,mt,dbCh)


        go func(cacheCh, dbCh <- chan Book) {
            select {
                case b := <-cacheCh:
                    fmt.Println("from cache")
                    fmt.Println(b)
                    <-dbCh
                case b := <-dbCh:
                    fmt.Println("from database")
                    fmt.Println(b)

            }
        }(cacheCh,dbCh)

        //fmt.Printf("Book not found with id: %v\n", id)
        //time.Sleep(550 * time.Millisecond)
        wg.Wait()
    }
}

func queryCache(id int, mt *sync.RWMutex) (Book, bool ) {
    mt.RLock()
    b, ok := cache[id]
    mt.RUnlock()
    return b,ok
}

func queryDatabase(id int, mt *sync.RWMutex) (Book, bool) {
    for _, b := range books {
        if b.ID == id {
            mt.Lock()
            cache[id] = b
            mt.Unlock()
            return b, true
        }
    }

    return Book{}, false
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you provide more details and background on your issue.

Comment: Can you also supply the exact error message that you receive when running the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider what `main` is doing every time it loops (without the `<-dbCh`):

```golang
wg.Add(2)
go func(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, mt *sync.RWMutex, ch chan<- Book) {
    // IF in cache then send book to cacheCh (will block if nothing receiving on cacheCh)
    wg.Done()
}(id, wg, mt, cacheCh)

go func(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, mt *sync.RWMutex, ch chan<- Book) {
    // IF in data base then send book to dbCh (will block if nothing receiving on dbCh)
    wg.Done()
}(id, wg, mt, dbCh)

go func(cacheCh, dbCh <-chan Book) {
    // RECEIVE ONE book from EITHER cacheCh or dbCh and process it 
}(cacheCh, dbCh)
wg.Wait()
```

So each iteration one of three things can happen:

1. The book is not in the database OR cache so nothing is written to a channel. In this case the program will continue (this may become an issue over time as you will end up with extra go-routines running that are waiting on data from one of the channels).
2. The database returns a value that is not in the cache. This is fine; the go routine waiting for the data will receive the value and all is good.
3. Both the database and cache return a value.

The issue is situation 3. The go routine waiting for data exits as soon as it receives data from one of the two channels. Assuming that the first value comes from the cache this means that `dbCh` is not emptied.

On the next iteration of the loop the `select` will immediately grab the value from `dbCh` meaning that sending to either channel will block (from [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types): " If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready"). The upshot of this is that `wg.Done()` will not be called so `wg.Wait()` will not return = deadlock.

Adding `<-dbCh` is a work around based on the assumption that if a value is received from the cache then there will also be one coming from the database.

Note that this code makes a few assumptions that may not always be valid in a real system:

1. It assumes that there will never be a situation where there is a book in the cache but not the database (what happens if a book is removed from the database or the database goes down?).
2. When a book is in both the cache and database it assumes that the value from the cache will always be received first. Generally you would expect this to be the case but I would not feel safe taking the risk.

Comment: You r a god send. thank you